# Replicating a file attachment control without Infopath?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, development

I'm building a form purely in SharePoint Designer and unfortunately don't have Infopath at my disposal (business requirement).

I have listed the attachments available on the form using the following:

```
<tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                            <script>
          var elm = document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsTable&quot;);
          if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
          document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsRow&quot;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;
        </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Above this I'd like to mimic Infopath's attachments button which shows the dialog for users to quickly attach a file (clicking the ribbon isn't as obvious to the user). This button:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Similar: http://vishalmarnepune.blogspot.in/2013/02/how-to-add-attach-file-control-on.html

Comment: Didn't the link I posted work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id="btnAttachFile" onclick="javascript:UploadAttachment();" type="button" value="Click here to attach a file">
```